# Is there a way to switch out of S mode on Windows 10 without using the store or Wi-FI

Tags: windows-10

Trying to run apps I receive the message "For performance and security, this mode of windows only runs Microsoft-verified apps". It appears I am in "S mode" and to switch out of it I need to go to the Microsoft Store. However, I cannot connect to Wi-Fi with this computer. Is there anyway I can switch out of it without using the Store or Wi-Fi?

Comment: In a situation where you cannot connect to the internet, one typically would just reinstall Windows 10 Home or Windows 10 Professional, in order to have an installation NOT in S Mode.

Comment: Or use another OS. For example, Linux can run many Windows apps under wine. You can even boot Linux from USB for those occasions you need to do this, if you don't want to install it. E.G.: https://itsfoss.com/create-live-usb-of-ubuntu-in-windows/

Answer (score 0):

There are some articles online regarding this which I would suggest reading.
You can purchase USB Wi-Fi dongles which would enable you to get the computer online.
I would personally recommend getting it online and doing it through the store, this way is the official way to do it and would prevent you from running into further complications.

Comment: Why do you dupplicate your answer?